# Cannot establish connection from Python to SQL Server after pymssql is installed

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x

Cannot establish connection from Python to SQL Server after pymssql is installed:

[image]

Here is my script

[image]

Comment: what is the error Ruben?

Comment: Post the error text, not the images. Images can't be copied, executed or googled. In this case, *read* it as well - it says the library wasn't found. Did you install the library in the first place? Did you run `pip install pymssql` ?

Comment: Check the Getting Started instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pymssql/python-sql-driver-pymssql?view=sql-server-ver15) to install the library and connect to the database. BTW you use `import pymssql` and then try to use `pyodbc` instead

Comment: This usually happens in three cases: 1/ the install failed but you didn't noticed it (yes, this does happen, I've seen it a couple times already, and it even happened to me once), 2/ the install succeeded but for a different python version (it's common to have at least two python versions - py2 and py3 - installed on a same system), 3/ the install succeeded but in a different environment (if you use virtualenv or similar tool). There might also be Windows-specific issues, can't tell...

Comment: Hello, Thank you for answering me. I will try to see if I can move forward following your instructions. Also I will not fail to put the script and not the images as you said. Thank you and see you soon.